# Read CSV and create different arrays

Tags: perl, arrays

I am creating a script to read values from csv files and use the values for other taskes. I have written the below code to read values.

```
sample file:

site,type,2009-01-01,2009-01-02,....
X,A,12,10,...
X,B,10,23,...
Y,A,20,33,...
Y,B,3,12,...

and so on....
```

Code:

```
my @value;
while (<INFILE>) {
    next if $_ !~ /B/;
        my ($v1, $v2, @v3) = split /[,]/, $_;
        push(@value, @v3);
}
```

it gives me all the values of type B. I need help to create different arrays for each type B values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this [link](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html#Growing-Your-Own). Hope this helps you.

Comment: `perldoc perllol` is good, though I find `perldoc perldsc` even more helpful (though more complex. Note that you can get the latest version of all of Perl's documentation online here http://perldoc.perl.org/. You should also be able to get the documentation in a terminal at any time (assuming a reasonably standard Perl installation - though some operating systems remove the docs).

Answer (score 3):

Reading CSV files is harder than most of us thought at first. It even turns out that reading CSV files is frustratingly hard. Thus my recommendation is to **not** do this yourself, but to use [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_XS) instead.

Comment: It looks so simple at first, but then it's not.

Answer (score 2):

From what I comprehend, you want to use a list of lists:

```
my @value;
while (<INFILE>) {
    next if $_ !~ /B/;
    chomp;
    my ( $v1, $v2, @v3 ) = split /[,]/, $_;
    push @value, [@v3];  # This creates a list of lists
}

use Data::Dumper::Simple;

print Dumper @value;
```